# Cleaning up a remote tree after a rebase

Tags: git

After pushing a rebase to a bare remote and running `git gc --aggressive --prune=now` on the remote, what else is needed to force the commit history of the remote to indicate the same history that a new checkout from that remote would, that is no indication of the rebase? For example, what needs to be done on the remote to remove the history completely and show only the single squashed commit:

```
$ mkdir test

$ cd test

$ git init

$ touch foo

$ git add foo

$ git commit -m 'Initial commit.'

$ git remote add origin ssh://user@git.domain.com:29418/~user/test.git

$ git push -u origin master

$ for i in {1..10}
> do
>   echo $i >>foo
>   git add -u
>   git commit -m "Adding $i to foo."
>   git push origin master
> done

$ git reset --soft 99a31c5906f82b333ca5c6204a3f83e3f100d4e7

$ cat foo
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

$ git commit --amend --no-edit

$ git push origin master --force

# On the git server inside the bare repo:

[root@server test.git]# git log --graph --all --oneline
* 8068d90 push
* 203f010 push
* 58b851d push
* 5e385c9 push
* 3c3a5b2 push
* 5b40efd push
* 558d8e1 push
* 61e170a push
* d1b60df push
* 36f44a8 push
* 3056f9c push
* e9e8fc6 push
* e40692c Created branch refs/meta/gitblit/reflog
* 327e77a Initial commit.
```

Comment: You should not even need the `git gc` step. Once the references are updated, any fresh clone of the bare repository will show the new commit graph: the clone will have no entry point into the old unused commits. If your question has to do with *security* (whether sensitive data can be reconstructed), that's a different problem, though.

Comment: When interrogating the remote, the commit history is dirty. The desire is only to leave the repo in a state indicative of a real "initial commit" state as a result of the preparations that went into developing that repo were not intended to be pushed (there are several).

Comment: (TL:DR: add a [mcve] to your question.) You say: *When interrogating the remote, the commit history is dirty* ... but I don't believe it, at least not without an example. The remote is a `--bare` clone, and presumably has nothing but its own tag and branch name references. Once you update those, there's no way to find the previous commits. If you're looking at some other copy of the repository, though, that *other copy* can easily still retain the hash IDs of the original commits.

Comment: Sorry @torek, example added.

Comment: I'm still pretty confused as to what you've run and what it did. The example shows some Git commands, but no output from them, and the `git reset` command uses a raw hash that doesn't show up in the `git log` output at all, as if these are unrelated repositories (although the `git commit --amend` step shoves the given commit aside, so that's not super-surprising either).